# VueJS define computed logic in two components vs. in $store

Tags: vue.js

In my vue app i have the following computed property in two different components:

```
normalizeName() {
  website = this.form.website_id;
  let res = '', new_val = '';
  if (this.websites.find(obj => obj.website_id === website)) {
      this.form.name = '';
      res = this.websites.find(obj => obj.website_id === website);
      new_val = res.acronym + ' - ';
      this.form.name = new_val;
      return new_val;
    }
  }
```

Now, i have a state mgmt defined using the `$store` but the question is:
in terms of best practice and performance, should i define `normalizeName()` in the `$store` and use its logic from there or should i implement the **exact same** logic in two different components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realistically there will be little performance difference either way. In terms of your code duplication vs `$store` abstraction problem - personally I find that a small amount of duplication lends to better readability and maintainability. When compared to pushing that function to somewhere else.

[This article](https://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction) explains why that can be the case much better than I could.

You need to consider whether it makes sense for a `$store` to have a function for normalising a name. Also if more than just these two component use the store - that function probably belongs in the components themselves rather than in the store. To me that normalisation functionality would look out of place in a store.

Perhaps if you thought that function was going to be needed to be implemented a 3rd time, then you should find a way to move it elsewhere for the sake of consistency/convenience.